# Easiest way to upload screenshot to Facebook?

Tags: chrome, facebook, screenshot

Why is this so hard? I just want to select part of my screen, and then have it be either uploaded to my Facebook in an album (best), or posted on my Facebook timeline as a linked image (acceptable).

The answer *might*  be [FireShot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/capture-webpage-screensho/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg?hl=en), but I don't like the idea of paying $40 just to find out.  Or at all. Ever.  The free version is great for taking a snapshot, but getting it to upload anywhere is hard, and even if you do, it doesn't make a Facebook photo upload post about it.  So it didn't seem like a good place to go.

There used to be something called CloudSave that would let you right-click on images and do this -- and it was great. But it stopped working. And can't do screenshots.

It seems like such an obvious operation to have to take multiple steps for.

Comment: I miss CloudSave.  One click facebook share is such an obvious functionality, I really can't believe it doesn't exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem used to plague me, but it's very easy nowadays!

PrintScreen to take a screenshot.
Ctrl-V to paste it into a facebook box.
This automatically uploads a new instance of the image to Facebook!

(This does not work in Internet Explorer.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you have the windows snipping tool. I'm surprised that not a lot of people know about it. Search for 'snipping tool' in windows. It is a very good and light tool to select parts of the screen and saving them. You could save the part of the screen that you want and upload it to facebook.

Comment: That's not the easiest way.  The answer I gave is far easier - 2 keystrokes.

Comment: @ClintJCLYes but with your approach you don't have control as to what you select. You just select the whole screen. The question is about selecting PARTS of the screen. Please stop advertising your answer on other answer's comments.

Comment: Alt-Printscreen doesn't select the whole screen (I have 4 screens, 3 of them 1080p, printscreen would result in a 4K-sized image), it only selects the current active window.   So unless you need to snip a part of an active window, your proposed way is much harder.  Typically we just want to screnshoot a chrome webpage.  I should mention there is a plugin called Awesome Screenshot (google nlipoenfbbikpbjkfpfillcgkoblgpmj as the URL for chrome plugins can change) that does a great job internally doing this in Chrome, but obviously isn't a solution for other programs.

Comment: It's your question mate, whatever you say!

Comment: Lol, it's my question, but I did phrase it vaguely, so I enjoyed your answer, even if it wasn't the right one for me. :)